# ImportError: 'psMat' is not a built-in module

Tags: python, importerror, python-import, fontforge

I'm trying to build [gregorio](https://github.com/gregorio-project/gregorio/tree/release-3.0)'s fonts, which involves running a Python script using fontforge bindings. The script is written for python2, but I've been unable to find python2 fontforge bindings (I'm running Arch Linux). When I run it with python3, it gives

```
ImportError: 'psMat' is not a built-in module
```

which I've never seen before, and I can't figure out what it means. (This is as opposed to

```
ImportError: No module named fontforge
```

when running under python2, which I know means that it can't find the module (as expected: the fontforge package only installs in `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/`.)

Specifically, the script tries to

```
import fontforge, psMat
```

but is only able to load the first one, regardless of which one is listed first.

The only thing I've found that seems remotely related is [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787674/c-class-not-recognized-by-python-3-as-a-module-via-boost-python-embedding), but as far as I can tell, fontforge.so and psMat.so are properly built for python3, as is also suggested by being able to load at least one of them.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the script can be run with

```
fontforge -script script.py args
```

Fontforge embeds a Python environment, which possibly explains why Python seemed to think that psMat and/or fontforge were built-in modules (they really are built-in when run within fontforge, I think).

Comment: Thanks! It's a really quick&dirty way to run scripts, and it works just fine.